# __init__() takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 20 were given

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have extracted results from a website and result is in below format for 93 other plans. I have created a dataframe to store this information and later will export this dataframe to csv file. However, I am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Study/Web_Crawl/Test_WebC.py", line 104, in <module>
    df = pandas.DataFrame('Snapshot Date', 'URL', 'planId', 'postcode', 'tariffType', 'planName', 'retailerName',
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 20 were given
```

---

```
df = pandas.DataFrame('Snapshot Date', 'URL', 'planId', 'postcode', 'tariffType', 'planName', 'retailerName',
                      'retailerCode', 'state', 'effectiveDate', 'solarFit', 'discount', 'dailySupplyCharge',
                    'Controlled Load 1', 'Controlled Load 2', 'Single Rate', 'Off-Peak', 'Peak', 'Shoulder')
```

Result sample

```
Snapshot date 2020-08-02
URL https://api.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plans/dpids/PWR93173MBE1?postcode=2000
planId PWR93173MBE1
postcode 2000
tariffType SR
planName Powerbank Bis Flat
retailerName Powerclub
retailerCode PWR
state NSW
effectiveDate 2020-07-15
solarFit 
discount 
dailySupplyCharge 162.9629
Controlled Load 1 
Controlled Load 2 
Single Rate 17.9203
Off-Peak 
Peak 
Shoulder
```

Answer (score 0):

you using the parameters in a wrong way, below is the function signature, from ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html))

```
class pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
```

where data is

> ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame

so you should do something like this:

```
data_array = ['Snapshot Date', 'URL', 'planId', 'postcode', 'tariffType', 'planName', 'retailerName',
                      'retailerCode', 'state', 'effectiveDate', 'solarFit', 'discount', 'dailySupplyCharge',
                    'Controlled Load 1', 'Controlled Load 2', 'Single Rate', 'Off-Peak', 'Peak', 'Shoulder']


df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data_array)
```

Comment: It worked. But when I tried to append the data in the dataframe it sis not save the data. Not sure what am I doing wrong here.  df.append([Snapshot_Date, API, planId, postcode, tariffType, planName, retailerName,retailerCode, state, effectiveDate, solarFit, discount, dailySupplyCharge,Controlled_Load_1, Controlled_Load_2, Single_Rate, Off_Peak, Peak, Shoulder])